# AppCompatActivity with tabs at the bottom get to tabs to the top whenever a fragment is replaced

Tags: android, android-fragments, appcompatactivity

My app has two tabs that stick to the bottom of the screen. These tabs get to the top of the screen whenever one of the two fragments attached to the tabs is replaced by another fragment.

Here is my code that replace the fragment:

```
// Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
AudioPlayback newFragment = new AudioPlayback();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

And here is my container layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="0dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3px"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I replace the fragment using an interface which gets implemented in the main activity. This is done correctly and successfully.

Can you provide some advice on how to keep the tabs to the bottom after the fragment is replaced?

Comment: I think your container is not at the correct place in the layout xml. Could you please share the layout file?

Comment: Hi Arpit, I edited my question with the container code above. Basically, the container is the LinearLayout that embed the ViewPager and  TabLayout.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour that these tabs will move up as soon as you add a fragment in this layout. If you want to fragment to come before the two tabs make the following changes in your xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="0dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3px"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi, this time the replacing fragment will show right above the replaced one. Anyway to show the fragment in full screen?

Comment: just launch a new activity containing only this fragment.

Comment: Not quite the way I want to follow. But thanks anyway!

Comment: In that case change the  root layout to Frame Layout and nest linear layout inside it.  Them add fragment to the frame layout.